# React setState not changing the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an App component that has a state containing a property "faces" , which is initialised after an object

```
const initFaces = {
  left : [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
  front : [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],
  right : [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]],
  back : [[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]],
  up : [[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4]],
  down : [[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5]]
};

class App extends React.component{
 ... 
 this.state = {
   faces : initFaces
 }
 ...
}
```

now my app is constantly changing the state of the "faces" property so i tried implementing a button to revert it back to the original state . 
This is what i have :

```
this.setState({
  faces : initFaces
})
```

But this doesnt work , and this does :

```
this.setState({
  faces : {
    left : [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    front : [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],
    right : [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]],
    back : [[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]],
    up : [[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4]],
    down : [[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5]]
  }
})
```

Why does it not work simply by referencing the object that has the identical content that i just copied inside of it ?

Comment: Please provide a producible example, your code seems right. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

The issue happens because you are passing the reference to `initFaces` when initializing your state, so whenever `faces` changes (assuming you are somehow mutating `this.state.faces` directly, [which is not advised](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-direct-mutation-state.md)), you are actually changing the same object referenced by `initFaces`.

You can fix your issue by performing a shallow copy of `initFaces` when setting the state (and for this, you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)):

```
class App extends React.component{
 ... 
 this.state = {
   faces : { ...initFaces }
 }
 ...
}
```

And also in your button's implementation to revert the changes:

```
this.setState({
  faces : { ...initFaces }
})
```

[But if you are indeed directly mutating the state, consider refactoring your code to only change the state by means of `setState`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-direct-mutation-state.md).

Comment: This answer is wrong... How it has to do with the same object reference? Here you got an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-maxwell-s5k2k

Comment: The OP didn't provide a producible example, I'm pretty sure he just doesn't reset the state right.

Comment: OP probably is mutating the state directly, like in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-dream-ygf9c. But, if that's the case, this is not advised (hence the eslint warning). But, as you can see, the problem is reproducible. A more proper solution could be the usage of setState instead of direct mutation.

Comment: Mutating the state doesn't trigger render, and he clearly stated "my app is constantly changing the state"

Comment: We need to hear from OP for more details, but I believe he's mutating the state in such a way `initFaces` is also being modified.